# i have a given the position of the string like a1[5] but it is changing randomly then how can i search the string dynamically and extract the value

Tags: python

```
import os
import sys
def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Job_Status = str(sys.argv[1])


a1 = Job_Status.replace("{", "")
a1 = a1.split(',');print a1;

if a1[5] =='runstatus:null':
    print a1[5]

if a1[5] == 'runstatus:203'or a1[5] == 'runstatus:202' or a1[5] == 'runstatus:201' and a1[5] == 'runstatus:null':
    print a1[5]
```

## main()

```
a1 = ['creationclassname:NVBUPhaseStatus', 'runstarttime:null', 'exitstarttime:1516358894', 'nextruntime:null', 'policyname:null', 'runstatus:null', 'exitbytestransferred:1245184', 'averagesize:1245184', 'runstatusmsg:null', 'serviceid:NVBU-HIPUNL61260', 'jobid:63', 'clientname:AB-WIN2K12R2-64', 'exitstatus:300', 'title:job1', 'jobtype:1', 'ackedstatus:null', 'exitstatusmsg:Backup']
Output : runstatus:null
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Can you provide more context?

Comment: i am searching the string like this (a1[5] =='runstatus:null') and comparing, some times it is coming at a1[2] index position that time my loop is failing ..instead of this any alternate to search string and compare

Comment: So you just want to see if `'runstatus:null'` is a substring of `a1`? Try checking `if 'runstatus:null' in a1` before splitting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the position of a string in a list with the `index()` method:

```
pos = a1.index('runstatus:null')
```